# Trying to game the system should not break the system (aka need friendly errors when messing with dupehammer powers)

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, 500-server-error, dupehammer

I wondered what will happen if I try to edit duplicate links of a question which is not even closed. So I browsed to [this URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/originals/291914/edit). I was expecting a friendly error like "This question is not closed", but was greeted instead with the 500 Internal Server Error page:

> [image]

Can there please be a more friendly message when doing that, e.g. like we have when [trying to edit a locked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/9134/edit)?

Comment: Error description should change: "It's not you, it's us. **This is our fault.**" -> "It's not us, it's you. **This is your fault, dummy.**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added more checks for such shenanigans.

The page already returned a 404 if the user didn't have the right permissions, so I've added a check for the question being indeed closed as duplicate - and if not it 404s too.